# Camera tracking far away object for fly by

Tags: animation, camera

I am trying to get camera to focus on a far away object and track the object as it moves toward the camera passes the camera then tracks object as it moves away. basically a fly by.[image]I have included a story board to show what I am trying to do. I can get the object the fly by the camera and the camera to track it as it go by but you don't see the object till it's right on top of the camera. [image]

Comment: Adjust camera range clipping?

Comment: Thank you and I new it was some thing simple.